# 403 Forbidden using REST

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating this app for a school assignment which would allow you to look at your planetside 2 stats on your phone. I'm developing it in Intel XDK and using mainly javascript with Jquery.

The problem is, with the code i have so far i get a Forbidden 403 error. It's basically not allowing me acces to the data. I've looked up some stuff about the fact that Iam requesting Data from a server Cross Domain from a client. Which is automatically blocked by the browser, i've seen some posts which get around this problem using a few lines of PHP code. However I cannot use PHP code for this project. Is there any other way to get around this Cross domain problem using only Javascript?

Here is the code i have so far, this method does work with the Twitch API, and does not give me a 403 Forbidden error in the console of my webbrowser.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="played"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://census.daybreakgames.com/s:mark/get/ps2:v2/character/?name.first_lower=hawkleaf',
        type: "GET",
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain:true,
        succes: function (data) {
             alert( "success" );
            $('#played').html(data['character_list'])
                }   
        }) 
        .done(function() {
            alert( "blah" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );
        });
    //setTimeout(displayData, 1000);
$(document).ready(function(){
    displayData();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: user agent sent valid credentials but doesn't have access

Comment: You also have a typo on success (missing last s). If you switch to jsonp for data type and correct typo, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from some time ago but i felt that i should post the answer even after such a long time. as Benjamin Bau mentioned, i made a typo at the Success part of the code. This actually resulted in quite a few weeks of not getting it to work...